# C++ How to disable non-const function in derived class?

Tags: c++, c++17

If I have a derived class that has both const and non-const getters for its data, how do I make them private / protected separately in the derived class?

I tried to "disable" the non-const one and the compiler complains even though it doesn't need the non-const one.

Edit: to be clear, I don't want to disable both "getInt()" functions, only the non-const one. (or the const one, but only one of them)

```
class Base{

public:

    int i;

    void foo() const;
    void foo();

    const int&  getInt() const;
    int&        getInt();

};

class Derived : public Base{

protected:
    void foo();

    int& getInt();

public:

};

Derived d;
int i = d.getInt(); //error, getInt() is protected
```

Comment: Don't. This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle. Wanting to do this makes `Derived` not actually a `Base` anymore.

Comment: Change to `class Derived : private Base`.  Then you can make Derived expose whatever member functions to pass through to Base as desired.  Doesn't violate Liskov's Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getInt()` through an instance of `Derived`, and its protected implementation of the function jumps in before the implementation of `Base`. The easiest way to limit the access to the `const` qualified version of this function is to not shadow it in `Derived` and declare the instance as const:

```
const Derived d{};

int i = d.getInt(); /* Works, no getInt() implementation in Derived. */
```

When it makes sense that every instance of `Derived` is `const` qualified, you can restrict the creation of `Derived` objects:

```
std::unique_ptr<const Base> createDerived()
{
   return std::make_unique<const Derived>();
}

auto d = createDerived(); /* Pointee is const-qualified. */
int i = d->getInt(); /* Ok again. */
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I want is simply disable one specific non-const (or const) function and leave all other constness as it is.

Comment: As linked in the comments above, this is impossible, hence the suggested workaround.